# How to set Bootstrap form-control class to Angular Autocomplete

Tags: css, angular, autocomplete, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to set bootstrap form-control class to my anguar autocomplete. I have added class as explained [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete) and its not working in my template.

```
<div class="ng-autocomplete">
<ng-autocomplete
  class="form-control"
  [data]="userData"
  [searchKeyword]="keyword"
  [(ngModel)]="aarlistfilter.USER_NAME"
  (selected)="selectEvent($event)"
  (inputChanged)="getServerResponse($event)"
  [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
  (inputCleared)="searchCleared()"
  [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate"
  [debounceTime]="600"
  [isLoading]="isLoadingResult"
  [minQueryLength]="2"
  placeHolder="Search Users. eg 'Taha'"
>
</ng-autocomplete>
</div>
```

this is the style I tried, height, color and border-radius is not working as expected.

```
.ng-autocomplete {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px!important;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    color: rgb(117 111 111 / 87%);
}
```

Comment: share the component code.

Comment: @YuvaRaj in component I don't have anything special(other than explained in autocomplete link). Just a databinding functionality

Comment: I hope you imported it in stylesUrl

Comment: yes, imported. @Component({
  selector: "app-aarlist",
  templateUrl: "aarlist.component.html",
  styleUrls: ['aarlist.component.scss']
})

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz link of your code?  It is hard to debug with the above code.

Comment: Its difficult, since I am using Argon Admin Template